# Adding all the values below the current cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to display the total sum of all the numbers for a particular column. I want the sum to be displayed above the column as follows:

```
21   30
A    B
6    5
6    10
6    10
3    5
```

I know I can sum the values and display it at the bottom of the column using `=SUM(A3:INDIRECT("D"&ROW()-2))`, however I am not getting a way to display it at the top of the column.

Please guide.

Comment: Something like `=SUM(A3:A65535)`?

Comment: Yes thats what I am trying to achieve...

Comment: You can fake a column sum without getting a circular reference by using 2 columns as shown in [this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eaKmJ0IZsglc7OCLoH8j615m4SEQW4AyIc3oQSq5hHA/edit?usp=sharing) (It works exactly the same in Excel). Cell `A1` contains the formula `=SUM(B:B)`, but the cell is merged with Cell `B1` and then Column `A` is hidden.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comments and the previous answers I suggest following formula, entered in cell `A1`:

`=SUM(OFFSET(A$2,0,0,ROWS(b:b)-1))`

You can then copy/paste to the right till *second last* column.

You could also modify your formula in `A1` like this to achieve the same:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROWS(A:A)-2))`

But then you cannot copy/paste to the right...

A more general approach with your idea would be:

`=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A),COLUMN())))`

You can then copy/paste to the right till *last* column.

Some explanations:

- Both formula sums up every value in the range from `A2` till the bottom of column `A` (i.e. for Excel 2010 this would be `A2:A1048576`)
- It doesn't matter if there are blanks or cells without value; the formula sums up only the numbers
- I put `A$2` and `B:B` in the `OFFSET` formula to avoid circular references, since I'm writing in cell `A1` and I cannot write `A$1` nor `A:A`
- With the `INDIRECT` formula you don't have to worry about circular references

Further commenting (sorry, I don't have the credits to comment at the right place under the question):

- Phylogenesis formula `=SUM(A3:A65535)` could also do the work, isn't it?
- Didn't understand your question at first, because you talk of "*sum of all the numbers for a particular **row***" but then you sum ***columns***, isn't it?

Comment: I meant column, sorry for the mistake....and yes even I had the question...=SUM(A3:A65535) seems to work, then what is the advantage of the other formulae over this?

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that Phylogenesis formula was ok. The advantage (if any) of other formula is a more generalized approach.

Comment: I actually like your "A more general approach..." better than mine.  I've never used `INDIRECT` much in my spreadsheets.  Question: How does this hold up for calculations on LARGE amounts of data?  I've had the method I proposed take a long time to recalc at times.

Comment: Thank you Doug R.; actually I'm not very used to this "speed" tests, I can only add this, very subjectively: with my datasets (some hundreds to few thousands rows, few dozens columns) the calculation time is acceptable (...and I'm not very patient). Could you maybe point me to some resource to measure this kind of parameter?

Answer (score 2):

When I'm doing something like this, I prefer to **not** include any empty cells beneath the range I'm summing, because I've had errors in the past as the result of including them (usually because there's a cell way down in the column somewhere that I'm not expecting to have a value).  I'm assuming that `A` & `B` are your column headers.  Assuming that, here is how I would do it.  This is your formula for cell `A1`:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A$1,2,0,COUNTA(A$3:A$65535)))
```

## Explanation

I'm updating this with a brief explanation, per the OP's request.

According to [ExcelFunctions.net](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Offset-Function.html):

> The Excel Offset function returns range of cells that is a specified number of rows and columns from an initial supplied range.

The function reference for `OFFSET` is:

```
=OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
```

What this formula does is create a dynamic range based on the number of cells in the selection, relative to cell `A$1`.  This is an offset of two rows and no columns, which starts the range at `A$3`.  The height of the range is the total number of filled cells in the range `A$3:A$65535`.  The assumption here is that there are no blank cells in the range, which there were not in the sample data.

Comment: Can you please explain it? :)

Comment: Can your formula be modified to automatically work for both Excel 2003 and 2010??

Comment: I currently use Excel 2007 and don't have access to 2003 or 2010 to test.  But I've been using variants of this formula since at least Excel 2003 without issues.  I don't know the differences between 2007 and 2010, but AFAIK it should work just fine with 2010, unless there are some major differences in how some pretty basic functions work.

Comment: Actually there are some cells with no values in it...the values are fetched from the database so I cant change them. Will this function work for it?

Comment: In that case, it will likely not work, unless you have the ability to write your DB query to return a `0` in place of an empty cell.  You're probably better off going with @Phylogenesis' solution from the comments on your post and using `=SUM(A$3:A$65535)` in this case.